# Getting a reference to a UIBarItem in a UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I have constructed my GUI in interface builder, with at toolbar + bar items. Now I need a reference to the buttons (UIBarItems) in code, and I try with the viewWithTag method (as I have given the bar items tag numbers in IB).

Here is my code, but it always returns null!

```
UIBarItem *backButton = (UIBarItem *)[self.toolbar viewWithTag:1]; 
NSLog(@"backButton: %@", backButton); // returns nil
```

Comment: Is `self.toolbar` nil as well?

Answer (score 3):

you should look for the items in the 'items' property and not in subviews.

Comment: Couldn't work this one out. Ended up implementing with IBOutlets, which worked out fine.

Comment: That works fine thanks. With the note that you also need to take care about flexible spaces in the toolbar.